# How to use KNN to classify data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, knn, supervised-learning

I'm having problems in understanding how K-NN classification works in MATLAB.´
Here's the problem, I have a large dataset (65 features for over 1500 subjects) and its respective classes' label (0 or 1).
According to what's been explained to me, I have to divide the data into training, test and validation subsets to perform supervised training on the data, and classify it via K-NN.
First of all, what's the best ratio to divide the 3 subgroups (1/3 of the size of the dataset each?).

I've looked into ClassificationKNN/fitcknn functions, as well as the crossval function (idealy to divide data), but I'm really not sure how to use them.

To sum up, I wanted to
- divide data into 3 groups
- "train" the KNN (I know it's not a method that requires training, but the equivalent to training) with the training subset
- classify the test subset and get it's classification error/performance
- what's the point of having a validation test?

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance

**EDIT:** I think I was able to do it, but, if that's not asking too much, could you see if I missed something? This is my code, for a random case:

```
nfeats=60;ninds=1000;
trainRatio=0.8;valRatio=.1;testRatio=.1;
kmax=100; %for instance...
data=randi(100,nfeats,ninds);
class=randi(2,1,ninds);
[trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividerand(1000,trainRatio,valRatio,testRatio);
train=data(:,trainInd);
test=data(:,testInd);
val=data(:,valInd);
train_class=class(:,trainInd);
test_class=class(:,testInd);
val_class=class(:,valInd);
precisionmax=0;
koptimal=0;
for know=1:kmax
      %is it the same thing use knnclassify or fitcknn+predict??
      predicted_class = knnclassify(val', train', train_class',know);
      mdl = fitcknn(train',train_class','NumNeighbors',know) ;
      label = predict(mdl,val');
      consistency=sum(label==val_class')/length(val_class);
      if consistency>precisionmax
          precisionmax=consistency;
          koptimal=know;
      end
  end
mdl_final = fitcknn(train',train_class','NumNeighbors',know) ;
label_final = predict(mdl,test');
consistency_final=sum(label==test_class')/length(test_class);
```

Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: I don't know too much about K-NN in terms of MATLAB, but I think the first answer in this link explains why you have three subsets: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9357/why-only-three-partitions-training-validation-test.
To summarize (in case you don't want to read it), testing is to initially fit your model, validation is to adjust and then pick the best fit, and testing is to get a gauge of real-world performance.

Comment: I think I was able to do it, but if someone could check my code, that would be amazing. I don't know if there's a better way of comparing the true test_label and the predicted label.

Comment: Your edit looks good, but I'm not using your matlab version, and mine is very different, so I can't reliably acknowledge. Sorry. You should use some real-world data with an obvious features-class-relation to test your program, not random data and class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your **1st question** *"what's the best ratio to divide the 3 subgroups"* there are only rules of thumb:

1. The amount of training data is most important. The more the better.
   Thus, make it as big as possible and definitely bigger than the test or validation data.
2. Test and validation data have a similar function, so it is convenient to assign them the same amount
   of data. But it is important to have enough data to be able to recognize over-adaptation. So, they
   should be picked from the data basis fully randomly.

Consequently, a 50/25/25 or 60/20/20 partitioning is quite common. But if your total amount of data is small in relation to the total number of weights of your chosen topology (e.g. 10 weights in your net and only 200 cases in the data), then 70/15/15 or even 80/10/10 might be better choices.

Concerning your **2nd question** *"what's the point of having a validation test?"*:

Typically, you train the chosen model on your training data and then estimate the "success" by applying the trained model to unseen data - the validation set.

If you now would completely stop your efforts to improve accuracy, you indeed don't need three partitions of your data. But typically, you feel that you can improve the success of your model by e.g. changing the number of weights or hidden layers or ... and now a big loops starts to run with many iterations:

1) change weights and topology, 2) train, 3) validate, not satisfied, goto 1)

The long-term effect of this loop is, that you increasingly adapt your model to the validation data, so the results get better not because you so intelligently improve your topology but because you unconsciously learn the properties of the validation set and how to cope with them.

Now, the final and only valid accuracy of your neural net is estimated on really unseen data: the test set. This is done only once and is also useful to reveal over-adaption. You are not allowed to start a second even bigger loop now to prohibit any adaption to the test set!

Comment: I like your answer, but I had a question: why do you weigh training more if your amount of data is huge in relation to the total number of weights? I thought if your number of weights is higher, then you'd want to use more training data so as to get a better fit. I just don't get why the reverse is also the case.

Comment: Thanks, Zhouster. You're absolutely right, I corrected the passage.

Comment: I get it, the purpose and how to partition and use the subgroups in theory, but how to do it with KNN?
I didn't get how to use KNN functions, even less how to manipulate its weights/topology based on validation results. Can you help me with that also?
Either way, thank you for your answer

Comment: That, my friend, is more an art than science! You need a lot of experience with training artificial neural nets to improve their accuracy. And I mean "a lot"! It is not days, it's really months. The best thing is to have somebody near to you being experienced with ANN and let you learn while he is doing this job. I fear neither stackoverflow nor any tutorial is sufficient to teach the feeling you need to do the right thing at the right time. But just start, and try, and learn! My advise: chose only one hidden layer and only few weights. Reduce your 65 features first, e.g. with PCA.

Comment: I think I was able to do it, but if someone could check my code, that would be amazing. I don't know if there's a better way of comparing the true test_label and the predicted label.

Comment: "The amount of training data is most important. The more the better.". Not true at all, that's a common mistake. This will likely lead to overfitting, that is the classifier tends to learn the structure of the training set and will not be able to generalize to previously unseen patterns. The training set should be not so big, but complete: in other words it must cover all the aspects of the problem you're studying.

Comment: @Alessiox and how do you achieve that without knowing when your training data "covers all aspects"?! The answer is: by using as much training data as possible! You ignore the very important fact, that the aspects need to naturally distributed. Small data covering all aspects overweights the rare cases, so that the final net is good at exceptions but makes huge errors on the mainstream input.